# Intercept the RAD Server endpoint requests

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria, rad-server

Is there a way to intercept all the requests to RAD Server endpoints ?.

I want to control programmatically the authorization to the endpoints, so I can define dynamically the permissions to those endpoints instead of being fixed and unalterable on the EMSServer.ini.

The documentation says that for programmatic control I have to check and raise my exceptions on my custom resources.

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/RAD_Server_Engine_Authorization#Programmatic_Control

> **Programmatic Control**
>
> You can create a new Extending the RAD Server Engine and add code that
> prevent accessing to particular RAD Server endpoints. In your code,
> you can check if the request is from a particular RAD Server user or
> from a RAD Server user in a particular RAD Server group.
>
> If the RAD Server user identified in the request is not allowed to
> access the endpoint, the custom resource should raise an exception (to
> indicate that the request is unauthorized).

It works, I can manually check on every endpoint if the user has permissions to execute that endpoint.

```
[ResourceSuffix('/item/{id}')]
procedure GetItem(const AContext: TEndpointContext; const ARequest: TEndpointRequest; const AResponse: TEndpointResponse);
...
...
procedure TEndpointCustomers.GetItem(const AContext: TEndpointContext; const ARequest: TEndpointRequest; const AResponse: TEndpointResponse);
var id: string;
begin
  TCustomPermissions.ValidateRequest(AContext);

  id := ARequest.Params.Values['id'];
  AResponse.Body.SetStream(TCustomer.Item(id), 'application/json', True);
end;
...
...
class procedure TCustomPermissions.ValidateRequest(AContext: TEndpointContext);
var
  User, Resource, Endpoint: string;
begin
  Resource := AContext.Request.Resource;
  Endpoint := AContext.EndpointName;
  if Assigned(AContext.User) then
    User := AContext.User.UserName;

  if not VeryfiyEndpointPermissions(User, Resource, Endpoint) then
    raise Exception.CreateFmt(_(rsNoPermissions), [Resource, Endpoint]);
end;
```

The problem is that having to call that check on every endpoint is cumbersome and easy to forget. Is there a way to intercept, on a single point, all the requests to endpoints ?.

I'm looking for a single event, or similar, like the WebModule.BeforeDispatch that Datasnap has, so I can call my `TCustomPermissions.ValidateRequest(AContext: TEndpointContext)` there and it will protect all the RAD Server endpoints.